# How to add a watermark to a TIFF image in C#

Tags: c#, tiff, watermark

I'm trying to open a TIFF image, add a Watermark and save it back to the exact same TIFF format. My code works great with PNGs but it was not able to open and manipulate a TIFF file. I tried using [TiffBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder.aspx) but I can't get it to work. I been working for 16 hours with no luck.

```
string fileName = "sample.tiff";
int opacity = 127;
int X, Y;
string text = "My Sample Watermark";
Font font = new Font("Verdana", 18.0f);
Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);   

// I need to do something here to convert the stream so it can used by the Image object.

Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);               
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity, Color.SteelBlue));
SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(text, font);
X = (int)(image.Width - sz.Width) / 2;
Y = (int)(image.Height - sz.Height);
g.DrawString(text, font, myBrush, new Point(X, Y));
stream.Dispose();
File.Delete(fileName);

// I need to do something here to save the Image in TIFF format with the same exact characteristics. 

image.Save(fileName);
```

I'm extracting the original TIFF from a movie file. Right now I'm using "Imagemagick convert CLI" to add the watermark but I'll like to do that using VB C# or not having to invoke the command line to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting the TIFF to a png and then back again using

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(filename).Save(filename + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

and then to convert back

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(filename + ".png").Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I don't want to add an extra step and convert the file to PNG. Right now I'm using "Imagemagick convert CLI" to add the watermark but I'll like to do that using VB C#.